# The equation 5x+7y=k has 7 solutions in which both x and y are non negative integers. What is the minimum value of k?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

**My approach:**

Upon solving this Diophantine equation , I get my generalized solutions as:

$5(3k+7t) + 7(-2k-5t) = k$ where $t$ is an integer

Now its given that x and y are non-negative integers therefore

1. $3k+7t\geq0\therefore t\geq-\dfrac{3k}{7}$
2. $-2k-5t\geq0\therefore t\leq-\dfrac{2k}{5}$

therefore  $-\dfrac{3k}{7}\leq t\leq-\dfrac{2k}{5}$ , giving a range of $\left(-\dfrac{2k}{5} + \dfrac{3k}{7}\right)+1  = \dfrac{k}{35}+1$ solutions.

Now how should I proceed further , how do I make cases on $k$ ?

Comment: So, do you want tof ind the values for $k$ such that the equation has at least one non negative solution?

Comment: It looks like you only need one more step to find $k$; setting that last expression to $7$ gives you a value.  Of course you should verify the result.

Comment: (k/35)+1 would be the number of solutions when 35 | k,   but what if that's not the case (i.e. 35 does not divide k) ? do I need to further break the inequality for when 5|k, or 7|k  and when none of 5 or 7 divides k

Comment: reminds me of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264664/equation-3x5y-k-has-exactly-four-positive-integral-solutions-what-can-be-the)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to employ a lot of machinery to find the minimum value of $k$ (see below). The solutions $x,y\geq 0$  are described by

$$x=x_0+7t~,~ y=y_0-5t$$

for some $x_0,y_0$ that satisfy $5x_0+7y_0=k$. Suppose the seven solutions (that have to be contiguous in t) span the set $\{t_0,t_0+1,..., t_0+6\}$. Then it is evident that by demanding that all the (x,y) coordinates of the  solutions be positive, that

$$x_0\geq -7t_0 ~~,~~ y_0\geq 5t_0+30$$

which implies that $k=5x_0+7y_0\geq 210$. We can easily check that the requirement is satisfied for $k=210$ with $x_0=0, y_0=30, t_0=0$, which shows that $k_\min=210$.